# how to select feature by drawing a line in openlayers?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, openstreetmap

There is one option in openlayers selecting features under the [box](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.box). But, I want to select the features when I draw line (draw with shift key down-free hand drawing). In my script I already implemented drawing and selecting options. I can draw line and select (multiple) features independently. Now, I want to merge this two. I want to select those features data which are touched by my drawn line. Is there any sample example available?

Here, I have given sample code -

```
//Selection property---------------------------------------
            var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
                [vectorLayer],
                {
                    clickout: true, toggle: true,
                    multiple: true, hover: false,
                    toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
                    multipleKey: "shiftKey" // shift key adds to selection
                }
            );
            map.addControl(selectControl);
            selectControl.activate();


var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                vectorLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path,
                {displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePoint", title: "Draw Features", handlerOptions: {holeModifier: "altKey"}}
            );
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register event "sketchcomplete" that will run over all features in layer-bo-be-selected and check if it has shared geometry with line sketched.

Something like this, unfortunately I can't test it now.

```
vectorLayer.events.register('sketchcomplete', vectorLayer, sketchCompleteFunc);

function sketchCompleteFunc(obj) {

    for (var i=0;i<layer-to-be-selected.features.length;i++) {
         if (layer-to-be-selected.features[i].geometry.intersects(obj.geometry)) {
             selectControl.select(layer-to-be-selected.features[i])
         }

    }
}
```